# How to create image by downloading manifest file and its blobs?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-api, docker-repository

As in title - is it possible to create an image from its manifest.json file and blobs that comes from Docker Registry?

Docker has 'save' command which is able to create .tar file of image, but when I look inside  that file it has more files and folders that let say standaolne manifest file and its blobs.

I would like to fetch manifest from registry, then its blobs, nextly pack it into .tar file and then be able to create that image using Docker's 'load' command. Can I do that by having only image manifest and its blobs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack but you can setup a local registry where you want to load the image and then follow the steps to push an image to registry using blobs and manifests as specified in [Docker Registry API Docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pushing-an-image).

After that, you only need to pull the image from the registry using `docker pull`.